# Can't replace Win32_Tpm.mof in \windows\wbem

Tags: windows

On Windows 10 pro I ran

> sfc /scannow

and in CBS log it reports

*[l:13]'Win32_Tpm.mof' of Microsoft-Windows-TPM-Driver-WMI, version 10.0.17134.1, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2018-08-15 15:14:41, Info                  CSI    000056f7 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:13]'Win32_Tpm.mof' of Microsoft-Windows-TPM-Driver-WMI, version 10.0.17134.1, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch*

I took ownership and allowed full admin access to the file, and then tried to copy over it but wasn't allowed access.

I stopped winmgmt (sc config ... net stop ...) but still I can't get access. Presumably somethings got it locked.

Can anyone suggest the best way of getting access to the file so I can replace it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh824869(v=win.10)) first; I mounted a Windows 10 .wim file and used the /LimitAccess option. After that SFC completed successfully, after a single try.